# html code inside php if statement

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add a video tag if the PHP code receives it from a `$_GET` method.

The problem is in the 2nd echo

```
<?php 
if($_GET['video1'] == NULL) {

}

} else {
    $vid = $_GET["video1"];
    echo '<video width="320" height="240" controls>';
        echo '<source src=' . <?php echo $_GET["video1"]; ?> . ' type="video/mp4">';
        echo '</video>';


    }
?>
```

Comment: You're already in PHP. You want `echo '<source src="'.$_GET["video1"].'" type="video/mp4">';` instead.

Comment: and remove 1 } before else

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not recursively embeddable:

```
    echo '<source src=' . <?php echo $_GET["video1"]; ?> . ' type="video/mp4">';
```

You are **ALREADY** in "php mode" with your echo statement.Therefore you cannot "go deeper" into php mode.

Why do you need such a hideously ugly convoluted statement anyways? Why can't you simply have

```
    echo '<source src=' . $_GET["video1"] . ' type="video/mp4">';
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
echo '<source src=' . <?php echo $_GET["video1"]; ?> . ' type="video/mp4">';
```

With:

```
echo '<source src=' . $_GET["video1"] . ' type="video/mp4">';
```

There is no need to nest PHP code clocks.